# replication warning: transactional replication latency alert not working

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, monitoring

I have set up a predefined replication alert (as outlined [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152496%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)) in SQL Server 2008 and the alert for **Replication Warning: Transactional replication latency** does not appear to work.  This is triggered by error 14161.

I found a number of posts around the web that indicated this was a bug, but the posts were so old, I'm not sure that it is still the case.

Is this still a broken feature?  If so, can anyone suggest a work-around?

**EDIT/ADDITIONAL INFO:** I see there are a number of scripts that have been highlighted in similar questions.  To refine my question, I'd like to confirm this is a bug and I am looking for a work around that is rather out-of-the-box... that is, just another way to write the SQL Server Agent alert to get it to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a work around (and to have more content in an alert), I wrote my own warning system that sends an email. http://www.sqlwebpedia.com/content/sql-replication-undelivered-command-count